# Error when using openrowset for particular record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, openrowset

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'Driver=PostgreSQL Unicode;uid=postgres;Server=localhost;port=5432;database=data;pwd=xxx',
    'select SanctionId,SchemeType,SchemeCode,CorrigendumStatus,AttendumStatus,yearofPlan,ReceivedDate from tesing WHERE SanctionId = ''-1'' ')
select SanctionId,SchemeType,SchemeCode,CorrigendumStatus,AttendumStatus,yearofPlan,ReceivedDate from testing where SanctionId=1103
```

While executing the above query, I am getting following error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check the source data against the target column definitions.

This happens when you try to insert, say, 100 characters into a varchar(50) column

Comment: Thank you for the reply but when i copy the column data manually i meaning creating insert script and runs it is working but when i am suing openrowset i am getting the error

Comment: @kallem: The error message is generated by SQL Server, not by PostgreSQL. So what you can do directly in PostgreSQL may not apply to what you are allowed to do from within SQL Server. Just follow the advice and use SUBSTRINGs or CASTs where appropriate.